# maximum recursion depth error when saving

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to update some other items of the same Model after creating new item and based on id of newly created item. That is why I have to do it after save. But I'm getting following error:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The `item` object seems to be valid and the for loop itself is not recursive and iterates through the `item` objects normally. Introducing save() raises the error. Obviuosly I don't seem to fully understand the inner workings of save() method. Appreciate any help.

The code:

```
class SimCardInTracker(models.Model):
    tracker = models.ForeignKey(Tracker)
    simcard = models.ForeignKey(SimCard)
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, unique=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tracker.serial_no

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimCardInTracker, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        prev_items =  SimCardInTracker.objects.exclude(id = self.id).filter(tracker__id = self.tracker.id)
        for item in prev_items:
            item.end = datetime.datetime.now()
            item.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: when you save a SimCardInTracker instance, it try to call `save` on *all* other instances having the same `tracker`. Imagine you have instances A, B and C all related to tracker T. When you call `A.save()`, your `prev_items` will yields `[B, C]`. You then call `B.save()`. Here, `prev_items` will be `[A, C]`, so you end up calling `A.save()`, etc... You don't have this problem using `Queryset.update()` because it doesn't call `Model.save()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found quite elegant solution for this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SimCardInTracker, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    prev_items =  SimCardInTracker.objects.exclude(id = self.id).filter(tracker__id = self.tracker.id).update(end = datetime.datetime.now())
```